# Assign Value Of "0" To All Empty Input Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input elements in the DOM:

```
<input type="input" id="triangle-base" />
<input type="input" id="triangle-height" />
<input type="input" id="triangle-area" />
```

On a keyup event on any input, I need to assign a value of 0 to all the empty inputs, but leave the fields with existing values alone. This is my JQuery so far:

```
        const baseInput = $('#triangle-base');
        const heightInput = $('#triangle-height');
        const areaInput = $('#triangle-area');

        function ifEmpty () {
            $("input").each(function(i) {
                if (i.val("")){
                    $(this).val("0");
                }
            });
        }

        baseInput.keyup(function() {
            ifEmpty();
    });
        heightInput.keyup(function() {
            ifEmpty();
    });
        areaInput.keyup(function() {
            ifEmpty();
    });
```

The console shows this error when run:

```
main.js:178 Uncaught TypeError: i.val is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.js:178)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at ifEmpty (main.js:177)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.js:186)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

I'm not entirely sure I'm on the right track. Thanks for all help!

Comment: Have you used `console.log` or read the documentation to figure out what `i` is?

Comment: You can use $(this).val() instead i.val

Comment: Using $(this).val() sets the value as 0 even if the value is not empty.

Comment: well `$(this).val("")` would set the value to "" and since jQuery object is thruthy would go into the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `$.each` callback functions are `(index, item)`. The item is a DOM node, not jQuery object. Also, your code logic is incorrect. `$(item).val("")` sets the input value to  (null). See the below fix:

```
$("input").each(function(i, item) {
    if ( $(item).val() == '' ){ // or $(this).val() == ''
        $(this).val("0");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty much on the line below: `i.val` should be `$(this).val`.

`i` is the index of the current item in the collection.